# Where is the location updates taken from for startMonitoringforRegion?

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, region-monitoring

Using **[CLLocation Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager)** I want to implement startMonitoringforRegion.

Where is the Location update received from to used to determine whether user enters or leaves the region is taken from for the **locationManager:didEnterRegion:** and **locationManager:didExitRegion**:?

Does the methods **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** or **startUpdatingLocation** affect the location used to determine the Region Monitoring?

Please check this question for the reference to the answer. [Region monitoring how when why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307538/gps-location-region-monitoring-recap-how-to-switch-on-off-the-gps-signal-icon) I have found the answer by going through the apple-docs and I am attaching the link to which I have answered the a question which pretty much contains the specifics of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

If you do not need the high accuracy highly up-to-dated use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. It is also recommended by Apple in most cases at it preserves battery and in most cases is sufficient enough. [More information here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) - highly worth reading, it will solve all your doubts.

Comment: I would prefer using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges but for certain cases once I get low accuracy region detected. I want to shift to high high accuracy region monitoring.
My question is whether the startMonitoringRegion does it takes user location and accuracy from the same CLLocationManger or from the service directly. Since we can define how the CLLocationManger updates its location.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by this: *My question is whether the startMonitoringRegion does it takes user location and accuracy from the same CLLocationManger or from the service directly. Since we can define how the CLLocationManger updates its location.* You can not chose source of the data and keep in mind that it is just desired accuracy which may not be achieved. Anyway all this king of issues handles CLLocationManger. Additionally, setting accuracy to three kilometers doesn't mean that you have to get a bad location coordinates. Have you read the article I attached?

Comment: yes I did read the article. Actually my requirement is just  to identify whether the user enters a region which is conveyed by a server. I am trying to avoid using the startMonitoringRegion method to avoid heavy battery consumption. I want to implement the startMonitoringSignificantChanges to decrease battery usage. But I want this process to run even when app is in the background. And since there are handlers for that in startMonitoringRegion. I want to know whether I can enable startMonitoringSignificantChanges accuracy to startMonitoringRegion.

Comment: so in that article is described about abilities to work in the background so your problem should be solved :)

Comment: I couldn't get the exact info from the article but you gave me an idea to figure it out

Comment: happy that it helped somehow :) even if not directly. With what have you ended up?

Comment: I have answer this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307538/gps-location-region-monitoring-recap-how-to-switch-on-off-the-gps-signal-icon